# How do I insert an indefinite loop in this code block in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

Regarding the code excerpt below, it is asking for input of either "land" the rocket or "orbit" the moon again.  There is a dead end in the current code if you choose orbit twice, as the code doesn't go anywhere after that.  I need an indefinite loop such that if the gamer enters "orbit," that the code loops back to choice5 and starts the sequence again until either "land" is chosen or any other answer given causes the game to end.  Unless there is a better way to think about this...  The code runs fine except if you answer "orbit" twice.  If I'm on the right track, any ideas?

```py
choice4 = input("> ")

if "FIRE" in choice4:
    print("\n")
    print("You have entered the Moon's orbit.  After one full orbit you can begin landing approach.")
    print("You are half way 'round in the dark side of the Moon.")
    print("......................")
    print("You are approaching the conclusion of the orbit.  Are you going to make another orbit or attempt to land?")
    print("\n")

else:
    print("\n")
    print("That is not a valid choice, try again.")
    dead()

choice5 = input("> ")

if "orbit" in choice5:
    print("\n")
    print("Going 'round again...")
    print("You are half way 'round in the dark side of the Moon.")
    print("......................")
    print("You are approaching the conclusion of the orbit.  FIRE thrusters to to land, or orbit again.")
    print("\n")

elif "land" in choice5:
    print("\n")
    print("FIRE thrusters when ready to begin descent.")   

else:
    print("\n")
    print("What are you thinking?")
    dead()

choice6 = input("> ")

if "FIRE" in choice6:
```

Comment: Look into a `while` loop. Also a [basic python tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) will help you a lot with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and everything I see seems to call an item from a list.  That's not what I'm doing here.  I have tried several iterations of a while loop but obviously don't know what I'm doing yet.  I will review tutorials again but so far, it's not clicking in...

Comment: A `while` loop is designed to "loop". Often it is used with lists but it is also common with inputs (user input programs just aren't common).  This is too much of a basic building block to programming that, although we can help you, you really should go through an entire python tutorial.